# How to handle "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in jsonp ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Try best to describe my question:
The following script is running at localhost:8080

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/getinfo?index=' + index,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "success",
        success: function (data) {},
        error:function(){}
})
```

If success, the return value is

```
success({"key":"value"})
```

However, if failed, console error in browser is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riEbi.png)
And I cannot handle it in error function. I even tried the .fail(function(){}) or setting "timeout" property, but it doesn't work either. Then how can I handle this error?

Comment: I used a plug-ins [https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) finally.
Actually, $.getJSON also works but back-end team just run special way to define callback name

      `$.getJSON(
       'http://localhost:8090/getinfo?index=' + index+'?callbak=?',
        function(){alert(0)}
      ).fail(function(){alert(1)}`

During the test, I found that if I add 'dataType' to $.ajax, then I can't use jQuery.Deferred(), I'm very confused about it.